# How to remove duplicated values in uneven columns of a data.table?

Tags: r, duplicates, data.table

I want to remove duplicated values in each coulmn of an uneven data.table. For instance, if the original data is (the real data table has many columns and rows):

```
dt <- data.table(A = c("5p", "3p", "3p", "6y", NA), B = c("1c", "4r", "1c", NA, NA), C = c("4f", "5", "5", "5", "4m"))
> dt
      A    B  C
1:   5p   1c 4f
2:   3p   4r  5
3:   3p   1c  5
4:   6y <NA>  5
5: <NA> <NA> 4m
```

after removal of duplicated values in each column it should look like this:

```
A    B    C
5p   1c   4f
3p   4r   5
NA   NA   NA
6y   NA   NA
NA   NA   4m
```

I am trying a solution proposed in another thread using data.table. However, I only get the first duplicated value in each column replaced with "NA", but not the subsequents.

```
cols <- colnames(dt)
dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) replace(x, anyDuplicated(x), NA)), .SDcols = cols]
> dt
      A    B    C
1:   5p   1c   4f
2:   3p   4r    5
3: <NA> <NA> <NA>
4:   6y <NA>    5
5: <NA> <NA>   4m
```

How should I modify the code to get all duplicates replaced?

Comment: hey @juancho, the solution in the linked post doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You were very close. Instead of using `anyDuplicated`, I used `duplicated` like this:

```
dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) ifelse(duplicated(x) == TRUE, NA, x))]
```

Try `dt[, lapply(.SD, duplicated)]` to get an idea of what the `ifelse` will do.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would be the *proper* `data.table` way of achieving this task:

```
cols <- colnames(dt)
dt[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) replace(x, duplicated(x), NA))]

      A    B    C
1:   5p   1c   4f
2:   3p   4r    5
3: <NA> <NA> <NA>
4:   6y <NA> <NA>
5: <NA> <NA>   4m
```

Note:

- `.SD` defaults to all columns, so there in this case there is no need to specify the `.SDcols` argument.
- Using `:=` avoids copying the whole data.table.