# Replace duplicated values with NA in a data.table column

Tags: r, duplicates, data.table

I want to remove duplicated values in each coulmn of an uneven data.table. For instance, if the original data is (the real data.table has many rows and columns):

```
dt <- data.table(A = c("5p", "3p", "3p", "6y", NA), B = c("1c", "4r", "1c", NA, NA), C = c("4f", "5", "5", "5", "4m"))
> dt
      A    B  C
1:   5p   1c 4f
2:   3p   4r  5
3:   3p   1c  5
4:   6y <NA>  5
5: <NA> <NA> 4m
```

after removal of duplicated values in each column it should look like this:

```
A    B    C
5p   1c   4f
3p   4r   5
NA   NA   NA
6y   NA   NA
NA   NA   4m
```

I am trying a solution proposed in another thread ([replace duplicate values with NA in time series data using dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54067963/replace-duplicate-values-with-na-in-time-series-data-using-dplyr)) using data.table. However, I only get the first duplicated value in each column replaced with "NA", but not the subsequents.

```
cols <- colnames(dt)
dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) replace(x, anyDuplicated(x), NA)), .SDcols = cols]
> dt
      A    B    C
1:   5p   1c   4f
2:   3p   4r    5
3: <NA> <NA> <NA>
4:   6y <NA>    5
5: <NA> <NA>   4m
```

How should I modify the code to get all duplicates replaced?

Comment: yeah sorry @chinsoon12 I'm new and thought that the other questions had been removed.

Answer (score 2):

Use `duplicated`

```
library(data.table)
dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) replace(x, duplicated(x), NA))]

#      A    B    C
#1:   5p   1c   4f
#2:   3p   4r    5
#3: <NA> <NA> <NA>
#4:   6y <NA> <NA>
#5: <NA> <NA>   4m
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to remove all duplicated entries from each column and so that the payload data are filled from top to bottom with the NAs arranged at the bottom. (This is different to [OP's other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59771098/3817004)).

OP's own attempt as well as [Ronak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59785886/3817004) leave `NA`s interspersed with the column values.

If it is acceptable to get rid of rows with all NA (like `na.omit()`) I suggest to reshape to long format, remove duplicate entries, and reshape back to wide format:

```
library(data.table)
dcast(unique(melt(dt, measure.vars = names(dt), na.rm = TRUE)), rowid(variable) ~ variable)[
  , variable := NULL][]

    A    B  C
1: 5p   1c 4f
2: 3p   4r  5
3: 6y <NA> 4m
```

If it is required that the result has the same number of rows as before, [Ronak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59771098/3817004) need to be modified:

```
library(data.table)
dt[, (names(dt)) := lapply(.SD, function(x) sort(replace(x, duplicated(x), NA), na.last = TRUE))][]

dt
```

> ```
>       A    B    C
> 1:   3p   1c   4f
> 2:   5p   4r   4m
> 3:   6y <NA>    5
> 4: <NA> <NA> <NA>
> 5: <NA> <NA> <NA>
> ```

Note that here `dt` is modified in place.

#### Nota bene

Normally, if data stored in a tabular format such  as a data.frame, date.table, or tibble, [each variable is a column, each observation is a row](https://www.jstatsoft.org/index.php/jss/article/view/v059i10/v59i10.pdf). Here, entries are removed from columns independently from the other columns resulting an "uneven" data.table with a "ragged bottom".

IMHO, this is a strong indicator that the tabular format may not be the best choice. Perhaps, a list of vectors with varying numbers of elements would be more suitable. However, without understanding the underlying problem this is pure speculation.

```
dl <- as.list(dt)
lapply(dl, unique)
```

> ```
> $A
> [1] "5p" "3p" "6y" NA  
>
> $B
> [1] "1c" "4r" NA  
>
> $C
> [1] "4f" "5"  "4m"
> ```